Как изменить политику в локальных групповых политиках через PowerShell?
Есть локальная групповая политика для электропитания, где можно указать конкретный план по GUID и никакое приложение не сможет его изменить. Я хочу сделать скрипт, который будет по guid устанавливать план питания и тем самым не нужно будет лезть в сам редактор. Но не могу понять, как и нашел только редактирования других политик, но это не то, что нужно.


политики - это, в основном значения реестра,  нужно настроить на одном компьютере, что требуется через правку политик, посмотреть что там в реестре появилось в HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Power\PowerSettings
и дальше уже при помощи Powershell экспериментировать. В помощь Set-ItemProperty -Path <HKLM:RegistryPath> -Name <PropertyToChange> -Value <NewValue>
